# Why is float32 more accurate than float64 in this case?

Tags: go

If I run the following piece of Go code:

```golang
fmt.Println(float32(0.1) + float32(0.2))
fmt.Println(float64(0.1) + float64(0.2))
```

the output is:

```
0.3
0.30000000000000004
```

It appears the result of the float32 sum is more exact than the result of the float64 sum, why? I thought that float64 is always more precise than float32. How do I decide which one to pick to have the most accurate result?

Comment: Please describe the behavior more precisely than "is more precise". What is actually being output? Did you look at the actual binary representation of each calculation? You can't rely on text formatting to always tell you exactly what an expression actually evaluates to. 64-bit floating point is always going to be more precise than 32-bit, so I'd suggest there's some kind of observation-error going on here, but your question is too vague to really know what exactly that error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't. `fmt.Println` is just making it look more precise. `Println` uses `%g` for floating point and complex numbers. [The docs say](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#pkg-overview)...

> The default precision for... %g it is the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value uniquely.

0.3 is sufficient to identify a `float32`. But `float64` being much more precise needs more digits.

We can use `fmt.Printf` and `%0.20g` to force both numbers to display the same precision.

```
f32 := float32(0.1) + float32(0.2)
f64 := float64(0.1) + float64(0.2)

fmt.Printf("%0.20g\n", f32)
fmt.Printf("%0.20g\n", f64)

0.30000001192092895508
0.30000000000000004441
```

`float64` is more precise. Neither are exact as that is the nature of floating point numbers.

We can use [`strconv.FormatFloat`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat) to see what these numbers really are.

```
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(float64(f32), 'b', -1, 32))
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(f64, 'b', -1, 64))

10066330p-25
5404319552844596p-54
```

That is `10066330 * 2^-25` and `5404319552844596 * 2^-54`.